# How to drag and resize the images in iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

How can I `drag` and `resize` images inside an `iframe` from the parent window?

I used the following code  but its not working.

```
$("iframe#test").contents().find("#draggable").draggable();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,May be it will work

```
    $("#iframetest").contents().find("#draggable").draggable({
            iframeFix: true
        }

);
```